# Python: Add numpy array to another one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
arr = np.array([])

b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
c = np.array([1,1,1,1,1])
```

I now would like to add b and c to arr.
The result I need:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5], [1,1,1,1,1]]
```

More general: Considering such a method:

```
def get_array(input):
    # …
```

I want to add the result I get from `get_array(input)` to arr like I added b and c in the Code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way that may be not very efficient but it works:

1. Convert the arrays to python-lists
2. Use the python-list append method
3. Convert back to np array

Code:

```
arr_conv = arr.tolist().append(b.tolist())
arr_conv = arr_conv.append(c.tolist())
arr = np.array(arr_conv)
```

Comment: Numpy converts it into flatmap for optimization. You might have to do a trade-off analysis to check which solution works best for you.

Comment: You don't need `tolist`.  `np.array(list_of_arrays)` works as long as those arrays match in shape.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> np.tile(b, (3,1))
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

Comment: I need it in a General way. I don't want to add only b. It's About adding any Array with the shape as b. So the next time I might want to add c = [1,1,1,1,1]

Comment: @LukasNießen: This works just fine with that `c`. It doesn't depend on the values in the array at all.

Comment: Of course, I again expressed bad what I really want. I do not want to "multiply" any Array by lets say 5. I want to add different arrays to arr. My program generates Arrays and I want to add them to arr. I just posted an answer my self, I guess there one can see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

One of many possibilities:

```
np.stack([b]*3)
```

or

```
arr = np.concatenate([b[np.newaxis]]*3)
```

**Edit:**
Since you are looking for a more dynamic way:

```
b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
c = np.array([5, 5, 5, 5, 5])
arr = np.concatenate([b[np.newaxis]]*3)
arr = np.concatenate([arr, c[np.newaxis]])
...
```

Comment: I need it in a General way. I don't want to add only b. It's About adding any Array with the shape as b. So the next time I might want to add c = [1,1,1,1,1]

Comment: See my edit for how to use it in a more general way

Comment: Then I get this error: `ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions`

Comment: That is because in the last `arr` statement, you are concatenating 15X1 matrix to 5X1 matrix

Comment: @LukasNießen Which code do you run exactly? And where do you get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Use `append` method from numpy as a flatmap output. Numpy (because of optimzations), outputs a flatmap:

```
arr = np.array([])
b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
arr = np.append(arr, b, axis=0)
arr = np.append(arr, b, axis=0)
arr = np.append(arr, b, axis=0)
```

Using append from python library (Non-flatmap output):

```
arr = []
b = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr.append(b)
arr.append(b)
arr.append(b)
```

Comment: This doesn't work: The result would be [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: @LukasNießen Then you can reshape at the end. like `arr = arr.reshape(-1,5)`

Comment: repeated np.append is slow.  don't use it